# TestFlight Leak

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I integrated testflight sdk in the app to collect analytics and I am getting a leak which points somewhere in the code written in the files I imported to integrate the sdk.

Attached is the screen showing the information about the leak.

Any advise?

[image: none]

Comment: Just tested my app that uses testFlight for this leak and I have it too. We'll have to see what testFlight says.

Comment: This has been around for a really long time I believe. Let me know what you find out!

Comment: Hey I wrote my query to testflight and they say this:
"I asked a tech about this and he said it's not a leak, but it's memory we use for the length of the application. It is something we can improve on and we'll certainly work on that as we have time."

Comment: Leaks for me too.Its probably OK given the above answer, and that its a tiny amount of memory leaked, though I am sure they could avoid it showing as a leak if they tried! This was enough to dissuade me from using the TestFlight SDK

Comment: Set a 'breakpoint' and see where the leak might be, would be a start.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the testflight integration code with in debug constant so that it will not leak in when your App is online. this may help you only when your app need to collect the analytics data while testing or dev stage.

```
    #ifndef DeBUG 

    // integration code here
    #endif
```

Note: you need to make sure the per-processor macro is added in the build settings for debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight has just released SDK v1.3.0-beta2.
In this version the memory leak seems to be resolved.

You can get it here:
https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/

For CocoaPods users, I've submitted a new podspec for this version.